# Code in latex for braces

Tags: latex, symbols

In LaTeX text, I sometimes need 'unpaired' parenthesis - `(` without `)` or vice versa; however, in such a case, delimiter check macro reports error. I found a simple solution: `\symbol{40}` and `\symbol{41}`, which aren't recognized as delimiters.  The same works for brackets `[` and `]` (decimal codes are 91 and 93 respectively), but doesn't work for braces `{` and `}`. Their codes are 123 and 125 respectively, but `\symbol{123}` and `\symbol{125}` produce something like dash and quote. I use fontenc LCY, trying both text and math modes.

I've found a solution:`\textbraceleft` and `\textbraceright`, but why `\symbol` doesn't work in such a case?

Comment: Maybe you should ask it over here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: MattAllegro, iI cannot realize why \symbol doesn't work for `{`-`}`.

Comment: @Spectorsky Check my answer! Sorry I didn't get it in a first instance, reading from my mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! This first code

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\symbol{123} and \symbol{125}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: a]

as output, while

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\symbol{123} and \symbol{125}
\end{document}
```

gives this output instead:

[image: b]

Adding

```latex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

provides the desired **font encoding** ([fontenc package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc)).

A (not-so-further) reading suggestion: [font encoding vs. input encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc).

Comment: MattAllegro, many thanks. I suspected that it deals with encoding. However, I use LCY (`\usepackage[LCY]{fontenc}`), and it prevents using T1.